# Couchbase: How to make cache persistence an option?

Tags: caching, memcached, couchbase

We have a memcached cluster running in production as a cache layer on top of MySQL. Now we are considering to replace memcached with Couchbase to avoid the cold cache issue (in case of crash) and have this nice feature of managed cache cluster.

At the same time, we want to minimize the changes to migrate to Couchbase. One way we can try is to maintain the libmemcached API and set up a http proxy to direct all request to Couchbase. This way nothing is changed in the application code. If I understand correctly, this way Couchbase is basically a managed memcache cluster. We didn't take advantage of the persistence cache items. We can't do something like flagging a certain cached item to be persistent:

```
# connect to couchbase like connecting to memcached
$ telnet localhost 11211

SET foo "foo value" # How can we make this item persistent in Couchbase?
```

I assume this is because all items are stored in memcached bucket. So the question becomes:

- Can we control which item to be stored in Couchbase bucket or
  memcache bucket? To do so, do we have to change libmemcached API and all the application code related to that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look into running [Moxi](http://docs.couchbase.com/moxi-guide/), which is a memcached proxy to couchbase. You can configure Moxi with the destination couchbase bucket.

A couchbase cluster automatically spins up a cluster-aware moxi gateway, which you could point your web/application servers to. This is what couchbase calls "server-side moxi".

Alternatively, you can either install moxi on each your web/app servers, so they simply connect to localhost:11211. Moxi handles the persistent connection the couchbase cluster. This is what couchbase calls "client-side moxi".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using Moxi, if we want to use a mix of Couchbase (persistent) and memcache (volatile) buckets, we have to define some types of proxy rules to selectively persist some items. Can that work?

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no way to have moxi decide, based on key, which bucket the value should be cached in. This would require a custom proxy.